# How is "Buffer" supposed to be used as a type with Flow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I'm failing to use `Buffer` as a type, e.g:

```
function toString(buffer: Buffer) {
  return buffer.toString();
}
```

Throws:

```
1: function toString(buffer: Buffer) {
                             ^ identifier `Buffer`. Could not resolve name
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOBlKAnGYDmAKAIxGGAFMMAuRAIWLIwEpEBvAKEUQ1KhAySJLkAdCnRZceBgG5WAXyA)

Am I missing something? I thought it would work out of the box but maybe I need to import some additional definitions? Couldn't find any resources on the subject

*(I opened an issue in [Flow's repository](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5389) but thought it might be well suited for StackOverflow)*

Comment: there isn't any Buffer data-type

Comment: @anand it's declared as a class here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.59.0/lib/node.js#L26 Shouldn't I be able to use it? If not, what should be the type of buffer?

Comment: I tested it on my local computer, and it is working fine, could be some issue with the flow try. have you tried on local?

Comment: Also working for v0.54.1 and below, but does not work for above version

Comment: Yes, it's throwing an error on my local machine. But you're right, it seems to work with v0.54.1 so it might be a regression or some changes. Thanks for digging, I'll wait for updates on the GitHub issue and will update this question as well.